# Coding a certain MP4 GOP with FFMPEG

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, mpeg

I have a .y4m video file, and I want to convert it to .mp4 using FFmpeg. The problem is that I want a certain kind of GOP, this one: `IBBPBBPBBPBB`. But what I get, when I set the GOP size to 12 (`-g 12`) is `IPPPPPPPPPPP`. I've also tried using the `-bf 8` option, but I get results like IPBBB... and the video doesn't play right.

Could you please tell me how to get the exact `IBBPBBPBBPBB` GOP using FFmpeg?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want something to the effect of :

```
-g 12 -bf 2 sgop
```

The `-g` flag sets the GOP size (as you already mentioned), the `-bf 2` says that 2 B-frames should be inserted between each set of P-frames, and the `sgop` strictly enforces the GOP size.